# PhantomJS external dependencies

Tags: phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Quite simply: When running PhantomJS with Karma does PhantomJS in anyway try to load any external modules it may need to run, via a network connection/internet?
I'm simply running JavaScript tests via Jasmine/Karma, nothing out of the ordinary. I'm not looking at testing load speeds etc, just straight forward unit tests.

I have a problem that everything works ok on my machine and other developers machines. But when it runs via Jenkins on the CI server, PhantonJS appears to hang. I think there are other issues, but I just want to clear this one up first i.e this question; external module loading.

P.S. PhantomJS was installed correctly on the CI Windows server. The windows server is fire walled so does not have Internet connections to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS sometimes works different as expected. Have a look at the phantom logs, it might be a syntax error in our js which doesnt't work in PhantomJS.  When I use jenkins I am starting a docker selenium container with a headless chrome in it and I run test against it.

```
docker run -d --name=grid -p 4444:24444 -p 5900:25900 --shm-size=1g elgalu/selenium
```

Comment: It turned out to be the environment variables on the server. The DevOps guy eventually sorted it out.